# Why not jframe shows button?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, frame

```
public class Benim extends JFrame {
    Container contentArea = getContentPane ();

public Benim(){
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Concentration");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack(); 
     setSize(800, 800);

    JButton start=new JButton("Start");
    JPanel pane=new JPanel();
    pane.add(start);

    setVisible(true);
    frame.add(start);
    frame.add(pane);
    /* setContentPane(Container)


     JRootPane createRootPane()*/


}

public static void main (String []args){

            new Benim();

}
}
```

My code is that. I tried adding to panel first then adding panel to frame, adding to frame directly. Adding a rootpane but still my button doesnot appear. I am trying to learn for 2 days but i am still at same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why another instance of JFrame? You are extending it, so just call `super()`.

```
public class Benim extends JFrame {
  Container contentArea = getContentPane ();

  public Benim(){
    super("Concentration");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setSize(800, 800);

    JButton start=new JButton("Start");
    JPanel pane=new JPanel();
    pane.add(start);
    add(pane);

    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main (String []args){
    new Benim();
  }
}
```

Reimeus also rightfully points out that you don't need to extend JFrame if you don't plan on extending functionality. See his example for an alternative implementation.

Comment: thanks this taugth me a lot of things.i will make a game like that http://www.mathsisfun.com/games/memory/ 
i will use a panel for cards and i will add  buttons start stop etc to frame directly. does it work?

Comment: Sure it will work. But I'm guessing you will still need to learn a bit more for that, keep it up! Sounds like a good exercise.

Answer (score 2):

The instance of `JFrame` that is shown does not have the `JButton` added.

Instead invoke `setVisible` on the `JFrame` directly

You almost never want to extend `JFrame` as no new functionality is added

Other points to note

- Call `setVisible` after components have been added
- `setSize` is unnecessary - let `pack` determine container size

This is the result

```
public class Benim extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Concentration");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JButton start = new JButton("Start");
                JPanel pane = new JPanel();
                pane.add(start);


                pane.add(start);
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);             
            }
        });
    }
}
```